# when installing roller weblogger it says couldn't find guice

Tags: maven, guice

I am trying to install Roller Weblogger, when using maven to build, it shows errors:

> Failed to execute goal on project roller-planet-business: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   org.apache.roller:roller-planet-business:jar:5.0.1: Could not find
>   artifact com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.0 in central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not find artifact com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.0 in
>   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

that means that he can't find this jar in maven repository : i did a search and i find this in repository maven :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

So try it because this jar exists already